# How to find if excel cell is a date

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

If I do:

```
print sh.cell(1,col)
```

I get:

```
text:u''
text:u''
text:u'eng'
text:u''
xldate:41450.0
number:11.0
number:30.0
text:u'Reality TV'
```

However, if I do: `print type(sh.cell(1,col))`, I get:

```
<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>
```

for all.

How would I get "text" or "xldate" or "number" -- i.e., the cell type -- from xlrd?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the `ctype` attribute of the `Cell` object.  E.g.:

```
sh.cell(1,col).ctype
```

This is an integer that indicates the cell type. You want to compare to `xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE`; [see documentation here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Cell-class).

Comment: Or compare to `xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE` as that's what the XL_CELL_* constants are for

Comment: Great, thanks for that and the documentation link to that section.

Answer (score 1):

I did this a hack-ish way:

```
if str(sh.cell(1,col)).split(':')[0] == 'xldate':
```

Comment: That's a horrible way - look at @Kindall's answer to see how to do this properly...